# How would I edit my class accordingly to call methods from main with out the parameters? Ex: g.count(filename) to g.count();

Tags: java, class, parameters, global-variables

So in my main class called testPara, whenever I want to execute the methods in my class paragraph, I always have to write the file name inside the parameter of my methods. For example: g.readFile(file), g.countSentence(file). What would I have to do so methods won't require and I could execute just by g.count(). Maybe a global variable? This my paragraph class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;           
import java.util.Scanner;

class paragraph {

 public void readFile(File filename) {

    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(filename);
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);

        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
           System.exit(0);
       }
 }

public void countSentences(File filename) {
    int sentanceCount = 0;
    String line;
    String delimiters = "?!.";

    try {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(filename);
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        line  = scanner.nextLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            if (delimiters.indexOf(line.charAt(i)) != -1) {
                sentanceCount++;
            }
        }
    }
        System.out.println("# of sentances: " + sentanceCount);

    }  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This is how I'm testing my methods

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;         
import java.util.Scanner;


public class testPara {

         public static void main(String args[]) {

    paragraph g = new paragraph();
    File file  = new File("story.txt");
    g.readFile(file);
    System.out.println("\n");
    g.countSentences(file);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could pass the file to the `paragraph` constructor. By the way, classes in Java should always begin with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

This makes only sense if your Paragraph class works with the same file the whole time. Then you could just add a field `private File file;` or something to the Paragraph class and use a setter to set the File object once. Like so:

```
public class Paragraph {

    private File file;

    public void setFile(File file){
        this.file = file;
    }

    ....
```

...and in the main method:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.setFile(new File("whatever.txt"));
p.readFile();
p.countSentences();
....
```

Of course you'll have to modify your readFile() method (etc) so they use the new "file" class variable.

EDIT: Or, as @4castle suggested, you could use a constructor to hand over the File instance (if your class needs this instance to work properly, this would be the right approach).

Answer (score 0):

Make `filename` an **instance variable** of your class `Paragraph`

```
class Paragraph {
    private String filename;
    . . .
    // constructor taking the argument for filename
    public Paragraph(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
        . . .
```

and have the caller pass the value in when constructing an object from that class

```
Paragraph g = new Paragraph("story.txt");
```

After that, your methods do not need the argument anymore, they
can just take the value from the instance variable.  For example

```
public void countSentences() {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(this.filename);
```